# How can I return a stream value in a http resource function in Ballerina?

Tags: mime-types, mime, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake, ballerina-http

I am reading set values in a csv file as a stream of records. Instead of converting them to an array of records I want to send the stream as it is in a http response. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ballerina only supports returning sub types of `anydata` type in http resources. But you can use the `http:Caller` object to add the stream as a `mime:Entity` body part in the response.

Lets say you have csv file like this in the resource folder,

```
name,department
Jo,IT
Jane,IT
Jim,Sales
Kim,Marketing
```

And you can define the http resource in the service as below,

```
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/mime;

string[] arr = [];

type Employee record {|
    string name;
    string department;
|};

service /api on new http:Listener(8080) {

    resource function get employeesAsMime(http:Caller caller) returns error? {
        stream<Employee, io:Error?> employees = check getEmployees();
        stream<byte[], io:Error?> payload = stream from var employee in employees
            select employee.toString().toBytes();
        mime:Entity entity = new;
        entity.setContentId("employee-stream");
        entity.setBody(payload);
        http:Response response = new;
        response.setBodyParts([entity]);
        check caller->respond(response);
    }
}

function getEmployees() returns stream<Employee, io:Error?>|io:Error {
    return io:fileReadCsvAsStream("./resources/employees.csv");
}
```

And using the `http:Client` you can consume this stream as below,

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/mime;

public function main() returns error? {
    http:Client cl = check new ("http://localhost:8080");

    http:Response mimeResponse = check cl->/api/employeesAsMime();
    mime:Entity[] bodyParts = check mimeResponse.getBodyParts();
    foreach mime:Entity bodyPart in bodyParts {
        if bodyPart.getContentId() == "employee-stream" {
            stream<byte[], io:Error?> byteArrayStream = check bodyPart.getByteStream();
            check from var byteArray in byteArrayStream
            do {
                io:println(string:fromBytes(byteArray));
            };
        }
    }
}
```